# Setting TextViews in ListView manually after ListView has loaded gets back to the original Text when i Scroll up or Down

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, imageview

Hello am implementing a listView which contains the An Imageview, when the user clicks on the image the text changes to let say 1, and the colour changes to red and vice-versa but when the user scroll down or up it goes back to the original Text and original imageview colour which loaded first with the listview, I tried using

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but this does not work

code for OnClicks:

```
holder.ImageLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                            resultp = data.get(position);

                            if(holder.ImageLike.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp).getConstantState())){
                            resultp = data.get(position);



                                new Like().execute();
                                String number = holder.likesCountTV.getText().toString();
                                int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                                int nene = num + 1;
                                String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                                holder.likesCountTV.setText(str);
                                holder.ImageLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic__red_24dp);

                                }
else{
                                new UnLike().execute();
                                String number = holder.likesCountTV.getText().toString();
                                int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                                int nene = num - 1;
                                String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                                holder.likesCountTV.setText(str);
                                     holder.ImageLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);

}

                        }
```

Comment: Please post the code where the text of the TextView is changed.

Comment: @NotGabriel I added the code for onClick and were textview is been changed

Answer (score 0):

ListView recycles the items in the list. Only the visible elements are retained.

You need to load the items in your Adapter when "getView(...)" is called

Something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(listItemLayout, null);
    }

    populateView(getItem(position), view);

    return view;
}

Hope this helps.
```

Comment: Actually am populating the data in my Fragment class and performing the onClicks  in the Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Besides updating the TextView, update also your dataset inside the onClick method.

So instead of only: `holder.likesCountTV.setText(str);` you also do:

`holder.likesCountTV.setText(str);`

`resulp.something(str);`

You **don't** and you **shouldn't** call `notifyDataSetChanged()` unless your whole dataset is changed.

Comment: am not clear with resulp.something(str); what does it mean

Comment: You should call your setter for likesCount and your setter for the image.

Comment: can you please give me a working example is still not clear

Comment: What I mean is that you need to modify your original dataset inside the OnClick event. You do: `resultp = data.get(position);` so you need to set the property inside resultp to the new value as well, not just the TextView. If you didn't understand, please add your `onBindViewHolder` and resultp's class in the original question and I think I can give you a working example.